# ES6 destructuring and spread operator not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a strange behaviour when destructuring an object with only numbers as key and using the spread operator to collect all other objects. This problem happens in my ReactJS app with babel set to es2017 and plugin "transform-object-rest-spread". I'm using normalizr to flatten my objects, this is why I get objects with numeric keys.

```
    const tmpContainer = {
        24: { v: 1 }, 36: { v: 5 }, 42: { v: 3 }
    }
    const action = { id: 24 }
    const { [action.id]:elem, ...rest } = tmpContainer
    console.log(elem)
    console.log(rest)
```

Output for elem: 24
:
{v: 1}

The output for rest is:
24
:
{v: 1}
36
:
{v: 5}
42
:
{v: 3}

The element with key 24 is obtained correctly but it is not removed from the spread. Trying the same code at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax works correctly.

When changing action to

```
const action = { id: "24" }
```

the result in spread is correct.

I'm really confused why this is happening or what's causing the problem?

Comment: property identifiers are strings **internally** `const { [""+action.id]:elem, ...rest } = tmpContainer`

Comment: Seems like this problem is known at babel https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4196. The merged commit seems to be available from version 7.0 first. I'm using Babel 6.26.3. @xadm: Your workaround works fine